# Get the social media links from a Soundcloud user

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible to retrieve the social media links (such as Twitter, Facebook, Songkick, etc.) from a user on Soundcloud, similar to how you retrieve a user website on Soundcloud?

I read in this old Soundcloud API thread from 2011 (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/soundcloudapi/AM8sIULAcLQ), that this was a high priority feature to be released. Is this possible yet (possibly skipped over in the API docs)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint is users/{id}/web-profiles

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users (Subresources)

Calls for XML / JSON:

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/3368879/web-profiles?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=121349e9

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/3368879/web-profiles.json?limit=10&offset=0&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28&app_version=121349e9

Comment: ahhh missed that, yes the web-profiles is the list I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: welcome, i used chrome dev tools to find it out, but its in the docs here under subresouces: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users