# Is it possible to get an artist's social media from Spotify API?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to ge an artist's social media (like Twitter, Instagram) from Spotify API? [Basically this question about Soundcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391870/get-the-social-media-links-from-a-soundcloud-user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the spotify [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/artists/get-artist/) that is not possible. However, it appears that an artist social media is available under more info in the app so I guess the info is not exposed via the API. Have you considered using the social medias API instead to look for artists?

Comment: I think that wouldn't really fit my purpose. I want to get all the artist's social media by entering their spotify name, since I thought you could get it from there.